# Loading a custom `mathastext` font causes minus symbols to disappear

Tags: math-mode, fontspec, mathastext

I use `mathastext` to customize my math font and its symbols. However, when using it, the minus sign no longer appears.

[image]

One answer is to use `\ang` command for the angle. This works only if we put use a minus for an angle. However, when we use the minus in an ordinary context, the minus sign would still be invisible.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes, italic, symbolre]{mathastext}

    \MTDeclareVersion[it]{times}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
    \AtBeginDocument{\MTversion*{times}}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{round-mode=figures,round-precision=5}  
\sisetup{scientific-notation=engineering,exponent-product=\cdot,exponent-to-prefix=true}
\sisetup{zero-decimal-to-integer=true}

\renewcommand{\deg}{\SIUnitSymbolDegree}


\begin{document}

\[ \num{625}\angle-30 \]
\[ -x \]

\end{document}
```

Also, why does the math font look different with enabling/disabiling `fontspec` when the math font should be controlled by `\MTDeclareVersion` and `\MTversion*`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using this instead of `unicode-math`?

Comment: do not use T1 encoding with luatex or xetex

Answer (score 4):

It is a mathastext bug. It clearly gets loss when trying to give the minus a sensible definition with a "text font as math font". You can avoid that mathastext messes around with the minus by using the nominus option:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes, italic, symbolre,nominus]{mathastext}

    \MTDeclareVersion[it]{times}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
    \AtBeginDocument{\MTversion*{times}}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{round-mode=figures,round-precision=5}
\sisetup{scientific-notation=engineering,exponent-product=\cdot,exponent-to-prefix=true}
\sisetup{zero-decimal-to-integer=true}

\renewcommand{\deg}{\SIUnitSymbolDegree}


\begin{document}

\[ \num{625}\angle-30 \]
\[ -x \]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `unicode-math` and TeX Gyre Termes (Times)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode=figures,round-precision=5}  
\sisetup{scientific-notation=engineering,exponent-product=\cdot,exponent-to-prefix=true}
\sisetup{zero-decimal-to-integer=true}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\renewcommand{\deg}{\SIUnitSymbolDegree}
\begin{document}

    \[ \num{625}\angle-30 \]
    \[ -x \]

\end{document}
```

[image]